# How to manage multiple preference sets?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have a list of items that needs to be configured. Is it possible to select one item and to edit it using the XML PreferenceScreen/EditTextPreference?

From my understanding, the PreferenceManager writes all settings to a file and does not let the user handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by leaving the multiple PreferenceCategory in the PreferenceScreen and then remove them programmatically using getPreferenceScreen().removePreference(pref). I store the items in a List and add swap them back in with addPreference.